# How do I send a dictionary as a Querystring?

Tags: dictionary

How do I send the `Dictionary<string,string>` as a querystring and receive on another page it as the same type `Dictionary<string,string>`?

Comment: language? framework? php? .net? jsp? Please be more specific.

Comment: Oh, sorry i was forget to mentioned. ASP.NET+C#